# Python Sending UDP packets through HTTP/SOCKS proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, udp

I tried to send UDP packet from proxy but proxy is not working. Why?

```
import socket, sys, random, socks, os

ip = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])
proxy = random.choice(open("proxy.txt").readlines()).split(':')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.connect((str(proxy[0]), int(proxy[1])))
bytes = random._urandom(100)
sock.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))
```

Comment: Can you explain what "is not working"? What are you expecting and what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send UDP through a HTTP proxy. You cannot send UDP through a SOCKS4 proxy either. With SOCKS5 the proxy might support it or not but in any case you have to speak the proxy protocol for this - which you don't.

Currently you only do `import socks` but this does not magically provide proxy support. Instead you either have to use `socks.setdefaultproxy` to set the proxy for all sockets or `socks.socksocket` with `s.set_proxy` to get a socket which supports proxying. See [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/PySocks/) for the details.